# 2 dimensional array vs simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'd like to know what would be faster at execution time and which cost less memory than the other solution.

I was doing a sudoku when I asked this question myself. As you know sudoku is a 9 x 9 grid array and generaly all solvers around sudoku are implementing array[9][9]. I presume it's because it looks like the grid you're used to play.

My question is simple, as the grid is always a square (ex: 9x9), what's the fastest and lowest memory consumption between :
- 2Dimensions : Array[9][9]
- Single dimension : Array[81]

Accessing values are in both cases calculated (if Array starts at index 0 and you need the 5th column and 6th row on a 9x9 grid)  :
- Couple of coordinates for 2D Array (ex : Array[5-1][6-1])
- single calculated position (Array[((6-1)*9) + (5-1)])

Is there any ways to test this?

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just use the structure that's most convenient for the algorithm. Unless you have millions of grids, it's not going to make any difference.

Comment: But to answer your question, a single array will be less memory, since it just contains 81 values, while the array of arrays contains 81 values and 9 pointers.

Comment: Of course that's what I told myself, but simply curiosity, if one day when up the sizes of the grid, it should have a difference

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Yeah, if you up the size of the grid to thousands.

Comment: I'm not planning to write a solver, but it was a question that wasn't leaving my head, I was almost sure single array was the less memory option. Forget to thought to pointers for memory in 2 dimensional array. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments the one array approach is the cheapest (memory wise)

As to speed, **timeit** is your friend:

```
import timeit



one_array = timeit.timeit(setup="a = [0]*81;s=3;x=2;y=1;", stmt='a[s*9+y*3+x]')
multi_array = timeit.timeit(setup="a = [[[0]*3]*3]*9;s=3;x=2;y=1;", stmt='a[s][x][y]')


print (one_array)
print (multi_array)
if one_array < multi_array:
    print('one_array is faster')
else:
    print("multi_array is faster!")
```

> 0.21741794539802967
>
> 0.13626013606615175
>
> multi_array is faster!

at least in python ...